# Selenium c# Google Chrome Drop Down menu

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm going to explain this the best I can.

I run tests using the 3 major browsers, firefox, chrome and IE.

I have line where I select data  from a drop down menu. Here is an example of what I use.
`new SelectElement(CPC_Main.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='orgVdc']"))).SelectByText("Selenium_vDC");`

This will select my element orgVdc and select the text value by Selenium_vDC. This will work perfectly for Firefox however it hangs and timesout for Chrome.

From what I can tell the issue is related to the default value of that element.

For example if default value of the element is "Test_vDC" selenium will successfully change it "Selenum_vDC" for all browsers.

However if the default value was "Selenium_vDC" already then Chrome will hang on trying to select that same value.

I hope that explains this enough, in a nut shell Chrome does not like matching default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had encountered issue like this in the past. I used to get exceptions like "The element is no longer attached to the DOM".  The issues(stale reference exceptions) like these needs a solid exception handling to make sure Automation execution is not affected.

You can try the below code. You can modify the below code as per your code set up.

```
  public void SetDropDownValue(string Xpath, string value)
    {
        var element = FindElement(By.Xpath("Xpath"));

        var selectElement = new SelectElement(element);
        //check whether the option is selectable or not
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, this.testCaseConfiguration.WaitTime);
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(selectElement , option));
        try
        {
            selectElement.SelectByText(value);
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            element = FindElement(By.Xpath("Xpath"));
            selectElement = new SelectElement(element);
            selectElement.SelectByText(value);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was working on injecting the above into a class and for some reason my tests on my 2nd screen started working. Right now i'm thinking that Chrome was just having a bad day